# Raspberry Pi 2 will not boot Hyperion

Tags: raspbian

I recently bought the light berry HD kit to set up some ambilights for my TV. I have all the LED's set up around my TV and have all the wiring set up (HDMI splitter > HDMI to analogue > USB video grabber and then the WS2801 RGB LED strip connected to a converter and then to the raspberry GPIO pins).

All the wiring has been done exactly the same as all the tutorials so I doubt that is the problem. The problem lies when i burn any image except the Raspbian .img file to my 8 GB Kingston micro SD card. If I load Raspbian onto it it boots up as normal but I don't know how to run Hyperian from Raspbian.

Hyperion is the program used to run the LED strip as an ambilight.

If I load any pre-loaded Hyperian .img files to the sd card the raspberry turns on but gives no video output and the red and green light stay on solid (no flashing from the green light meaning it is loading from the SD card) i have read up this means it cannot find any boot up file or it OS unable to read the sd card. I thought it might be corrupt but if i format it and again load Raspbian onto it, it boots up like normal again!

Comment: Does the image you are downloading say it is compatible with the Pi2?  The images may only work on earlier Pis.

Comment: Please provide a link to the img files that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Is it Hyperion you are referring to ?

Now I have no experience with it what so ever, but from what I understand Hyperion is not a OS in itself, but an ambilight implementation for the Raspbmc distribution, **NOT** Rasbian.

Furthermore it could seem you are trying to install a piece of software as an operating system.

Comment: Yes he said it he was having problems with a "pre-loaded hyperian .img" meaning an img of an OS with Hyperion pre-installed.

Comment: I think you are correct.  Hyperion's [official docs](https://github.com/tvdzwan/hyperion/wiki/installation) do not mention any complete OS image -- they explain how to install it on OSMC or OpenELEC, so I think the OP has been led down the garden path by some fool's blog.

Comment: user1133275 OP is misspelling the name of the very software he is asking help for. It is essential to understand just what OP is asking for help with. So asking OP if the real name of the program is what he is asking about, is pretty crucial, since if it is the case, then OP is trying to install a piece of software as an operating system. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't think you and @user1133275 are in disagreement; the person who downvoted this probably didn't leave a comment.  Searching "hyperion led" vs. "hyperian led" seems decisive WRT to the spelling error.

Comment: Hyperion is nothing to do with raspbmc

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/download/images/)
Once you have that working install [Hyperion](https://github.com/tvdzwan/hyperion/)
Note that Hyperion was designed for an older version of OSMC so you might need to change some paths etc to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

This installation works and has everything you need:

http://goemkay.tumblr.com/post/112069922221/lights-at-the-end-of-the-tunnel-or-how-to

Remember to change priority to 800 instead of 1100 as stated, cause it didn't work that way to me and had a while to figure it out.